# Whats the best way to securely publish a site post build?

Tags: .net, windows, deployment, iis-6

So, in your experience, whats the best way? Is there a secure way that's also scriptable/triggerable in a build automation tool?

Edit: I should mention this is windows/.net and I'll be deploying to iis6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some projects I use [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) to push out to live. It is built on top of ruby and makes deploy script writing super easy and uses ssh.

On other projects I have a tiny deploy app that uses bash to do an svn export to a temporary directory and then rsync it over to the live server. You can make rsync use ssh.

I greatly prefer the Capistrano method, even if your project isn't in ruby/rails.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like the sort of thing that could be done easily with SFTP. Take a look at [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (psftp and pscp) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) for Windows, or [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) and [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) for Unixes.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of your live site directory, use [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) to update that copy with your latest version, then rename the live and updated directories so that the updated version is now live.

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
cp -R /var/livesite /var/newversion
rsync user@devserver:/var/readytogolive /var/newversion
mv /var/livesite /var/oldlivesite
mv /var/newversion /var/livesite
```

Viola!

Edit: @Ted Percival - That's a good idea. I didn't even know about "set -e". Updated script. Edit: updated again at Ted's suggestion (although I think it would still work if somehow the cp command failed, and if cp fails you probably have more serious problems.)

Answer (score 1):

@Neall, I'd add a `set -e` on the second line, because you don't want the live site being replaced if the `rsync` fails for any reason. `set -e` causes the script to exit if any of its commands fail.

Edit: The `set -e` should be the first thing in the script, right after `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the recommendation for [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org), though if you're looking for a GUI-based solution you could try the [Webistrano](http://blog.innerewut.de/webistrano/) front end.  Clean, ssh-based, sane deployment and rollback semantics and easy scripting and extensibility via ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a small client/server app that encrypts at the source, pushes the files, and then decrypts at the destination. That's a little bit of work, but probably a trivial amount. And it's scriptable as long as your automation tool supports executing something in the file system (which I think all do).

The only downside is that you may not be able to get meaningful error messages on failure in your integration environment without a bit more work on your part (though depending on your setup, this could be as simple as sending error messages to stdout).

Answer (score 0):

hm, around here we use a staging "server" for testing purposes on the live environment (actually, its an apache virtual host on the production server) and [araxis merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) (a really smart line-by-line file comparison tool) to sync development and staging.

once its tested, just; replace the files on the production webroot :)

/mp

Answer (score 0):

On a freelance job I did, we set up three seperate enviroments.

- A Dev server, that ran continues builds using CruiseControl. Any check-in would trigger a build. QA Testing was done here.
- A Test Server, that user acceptance testing was done on.
- Production.

The workflow was as followed:

1. Developer checks in changes to SourceControl.
2. CruiseControl builds and deploys the build to Dev.
3. Dev is QA'ed
4. After passing QA, a robocopy script is ran that deploys the Dev build to Test.
5. Test is UAT'ed
6. After Test passes, a robocopy script is ran that deploys Test to PRD.